# Paypal classic API : Get declined recurring payment details

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Please help me, How can I get list of declined recurring payments/profiles using classic API.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that takes your payment profile IDs and runs [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API call for each profile and you can see the status of each one, the date of the last payment made, any past due amounts from failed payments, and more. You can then use the [BillOutstandingAmount](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/BillOutstandingAmount_API_Operation_NVP/) API to attempt to capture the past due amount for that profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where I can get profile ID's? We want to make a tool where user can all his recurring transaction details. I wish to get profile ID's using API. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: We do not have an API call that returns all previous recurring payment profiles. These profile IDs are returned to you when you create them. It is assumed the merchant would save these profiles in a database.